# Values aren't being saved in a queue in C

Tags: c, data-structures, queue, nodes

I'm trying to implement a queue in C using a linked list. I ran my code through a C visualizer and it seems that the values A-E aren't being saved. As in, one node will contain the letter A then when queue_enqueue is called again, another node is created that holds the letter B and then the previous node that contained A just, disappears... My code contains other functions like dequeue and one to check if the queue is empty, but I took them out to keep my code short and they are independent of the functions provided here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct node {
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
    char *value;
};

// The type for a list.
typedef struct list {
    struct node head;
} List;

typedef struct queue {
    List *list;
} Queue;


Queue *queue_create(void) {
    Queue *q = (Queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
    List *ptr = (List*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    q->list = ptr;
    q->list->head.next = NULL;
 
    return q;
}

void queue_destroy(Queue *q) {
    free(q->list->head.value);
    free(q);
}

void queue_enqueue(Queue *q, const char *value) {
    struct node *temp;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->value = strdup(value);
    temp->next = NULL;

    q->list->head.next = temp;
    q->list->head.value = temp;
}

int main(void) {
    // Create an empty queue.
    Queue *q = queue_create();

    // Add the values A, B, ..., Z to the queue.
    char str[] = "A";
    for (char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'E'; ch++) {
        str[0] = ch;
        queue_enqueue(q, str);
    }

    // Clean up.
    queue_destroy(q);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `q->list->head.value = temp;` This doesn't make any sense. Did you mean `q->list->head.prev = temp;`? Somewhat <O/T>, since you're just storing single chars, you'll make it easier on yourself if you do `char value;` and forget the strings.

Comment: I tried `q->list->head.prev = temp;` in a previous attempt, but it didn't do much... was still getting the same results according to the C visualizer

Comment: `q->list->head.value = temp;` in `queue_enqueue` ... _warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'char *' from 'struct node *'_.  Maybe you meant `strcpy(q->list->head.next->value, temp->value);`

Comment: If you want to append the newly created node to your list you have to iterate your list first to find the end which is free to insert. You are just overwriting the same node over and over again (and creating memory leaks doing so)

Comment: You are continuously just replacing the value of `q-list->head.value` and not advancing down the list in any way so of course nothing is getting queued up

Answer (score 1):

To simplify your problem you should begin with a single-linked list and in your example there is no need to use `char*` as node value:

```
struct node {
    struct node* next;
    char value;
};
```

You also might want to add a element counter for your list:

```
typedef struct list {
    struct node *head;
    size_t num;
}
```

and a function to create a new node with the given value:

```
struct node *node_create(char value) {
    struct node *nd = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if (nd)
        nd->value = value;

    return nd;
}
```

The magic happens in the insert function but it is no rocket science at all. You either create your new node where `head` is pointing (empty list) or at the end of the list.

```
void list_insert(List *list, char value) {
    if (!list)
        return;

    if (!list->head) {
        // first element of list
        list->head = node_create(value);
        if (list->head)
            list->num++;
    }
    else {
        // move to the end of the list
        struct node *nd = list->head;
        
        while (nd->next) {
            nd = nd->next;
        }
        
        nd->next = node_create(value);
        if (nd->next)
             list->num++;
    }
}
```

Also make sure to properly initialize your list with some `list_create` function and when cleaning the list take care to free **all** list elements before releasing the memory of the list itself

Answer (score 1):

You are not linking the chain pointers correctly.

And, setting `q->list->head.value = temp;` won't even compile.

For a doubly linked list, reusing a node struct as the front/back pointers (e.g prev/next) is doable but unclear. Better to redefine `List` slightly to use front/back--it's clearer.

Your destroy code is also wrong.

When appending to a list, the first time is slightly different than subsequent ones.

---

Here's the refactored code.

Since your code didn't change any of the list's `next/prev` pointers or temp's `next/prev` pointers, it wasn't clear whether you wanted to enqueue to the front or the back of the list, so I added both functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct node {
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
    char *value;
};

// The type for a list.
typedef struct list {
    struct node *front;
    struct node *back;
    size_t count;
} List;

typedef struct queue {
    List *list;
} Queue;

Queue *
queue_create(void)
{
    Queue *q = malloc(sizeof(*q));
    q->list = calloc(1,sizeof(List));

    return q;
}

void
queue_destroy(Queue *q)
{
    List *list = q->list;
    struct node *cur;
    struct node *next;

    if (list != NULL)
        cur = list->front;
    else
        cur = NULL;

    for (;  cur != NULL;  cur = next) {
        next = cur->next;
        free(cur->value);
    }

    free(list);
    free(q);
}

struct node *
node_create(const char *value)
{
    struct node *temp = calloc(1,sizeof(*temp));

    temp->value = strdup(value);

    return temp;
}

void
queue_enqueue_front(Queue *q,const char *value)
{
    struct node *temp = node_create(value);
    List *list = q->list;

    temp->next = list->front;
    if (list->front != NULL)
        list->front->prev = temp;
    list->front = temp;

    if (list->back == NULL)
        list->back = temp;

    list->count += 1;
}

void
queue_enqueue_back(Queue *q,const char *value)
{
    struct node *temp = node_create(value);
    List *list = q->list;

    temp->prev = list->back;
    if (list->back != NULL)
        list->back->next = temp;
    list->back = temp;

    if (list->front == NULL)
        list->front = temp;

    list->count += 1;
}

void
queue_print_fwd(Queue *q,const char *who)
{
    List *list = q->list;
    struct node *cur;

    if (who != NULL)
        printf("%s:\n",who);

    for (cur = list->front;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next)
        printf("  %s\n",cur->value);
}

void
queue_print_rev(Queue *q,const char *who)
{
    List *list = q->list;
    struct node *cur;

    if (who != NULL)
        printf("%s:\n",who);

    for (cur = list->back;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->prev)
        printf("  %s\n",cur->value);
}

int
main(void)
{
    // Create an empty queue.
    Queue *q = queue_create();

    // Add the values A, B, ..., Z to the queue.
    char str[] = "A";

    for (char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'E'; ch++) {
        str[0] = ch;
        queue_enqueue_back(q, str);
#ifdef DEBUG
        queue_print_fwd(q,"pushback");
#endif
    }

    for (char ch = 'K'; ch >= 'F'; ch--) {
        str[0] = ch;
        queue_enqueue_front(q, str);
#ifdef DEBUG
        queue_print_fwd(q,"pushfront");
#endif
    }

    queue_print_fwd(q,"Forward");
    queue_print_rev(q,"Reverse");

    // Clean up.
    queue_destroy(q);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's the program output:

```
Forward:
  F
  G
  H
  I
  J
  K
  A
  B
  C
  D
  E
Reverse:
  E
  D
  C
  B
  A
  K
  J
  I
  H
  G
  F
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Here's a slightly cleaned up version.

There's probably no need to allocate `q->list`--It could just be declared as `List list;` instead of `List *list;`

Just for grins, I also added a node removal function (e.g. `queue_unlink`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct node Node;
struct node {
    Node *next;
    Node *prev;
    char *value;
};

// The type for a list.
typedef struct list {
    Node *front;
    Node *back;
    size_t count;
} List;

typedef struct queue {
    List list;
} Queue;

Queue *
queue_create(void)
{
    Queue *q = calloc(1,sizeof(*q));

    return q;
}

void
queue_destroy(Queue *q)
{
    List *list = &q->list;
    Node *cur;
    Node *next;

    for (cur = list->front;  cur != NULL;  cur = next) {
        next = cur->next;
        free(cur->value);
        list->count -= 1;
    }

    free(q);
}

void
queue_unlink(Queue *q,Node *cur)
{
    List *list = &q->list;

    do {
        if (cur == NULL)
            break;

        Node *prev = cur->prev;
        Node *next = cur->next;

        if (prev != NULL)
            prev->next = next;

        if (next != NULL)
            next->prev = prev;

        if (list->front == cur)
            list->front = next;

        if (list->back == cur)
            list->back = prev;

        cur->prev = NULL;
        cur->next = NULL;

        list->count -= 1;
    } while (0);
}

Node *
node_create(const char *value)
{
    Node *temp = calloc(1,sizeof(*temp));

    temp->value = strdup(value);

    return temp;
}

void
queue_enqueue_front(Queue *q,const char *value)
{
    Node *temp = node_create(value);
    List *list = &q->list;

    Node *front = list->front;
    temp->next = front;
    if (front != NULL)
        front->prev = temp;
    list->front = temp;

    if (list->back == NULL)
        list->back = temp;

    list->count += 1;
}

void
queue_enqueue_back(Queue *q,const char *value)
{
    Node *temp = node_create(value);
    List *list = &q->list;

    Node *back = list->back;
    temp->prev = back;
    if (back != NULL)
        back->next = temp;
    list->back = temp;

    if (list->front == NULL)
        list->front = temp;

    list->count += 1;
}

int
queue_print_node(Node *cur,int totlen)
{
    int curlen;

    curlen = strlen(cur->value);

    if ((totlen + curlen + 1) >= 78) {
        fputc('\n',stdout);
        totlen = 0;
    }

    fputc(' ',stdout);
    totlen += 1;

    fputs(cur->value,stdout);
    totlen += curlen;

    return totlen;
}

void
queue_print_fwd(Queue *q,const char *who)
{
    List *list = &q->list;
    Node *cur;
    int totlen = 0;

    if (who != NULL)
        printf("%s:\n",who);

    for (cur = list->front;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next)
        totlen = queue_print_node(cur,totlen);

    if (totlen > 0)
        fputc('\n',stdout);
}

void
queue_print_rev(Queue *q,const char *who)
{
    List *list = &q->list;
    Node *cur;
    int totlen = 0;

    if (who != NULL)
        printf("%s:\n",who);

    for (cur = list->back;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->prev)
        totlen = queue_print_node(cur,totlen);

    if (totlen > 0)
        fputc('\n',stdout);
}

int
main(void)
{
    // Create an empty queue.
    Queue *q = queue_create();

    // Add the values A, B, ..., Z to the queue.
    char str[] = "A";

    for (char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'E'; ch++) {
        str[0] = ch;
        queue_enqueue_back(q, str);
#ifdef DEBUG
        queue_print_fwd(q,"pushback");
#endif
    }

    for (char ch = 'K'; ch >= 'F'; ch--) {
        str[0] = ch;
        queue_enqueue_front(q, str);
#ifdef DEBUG
        queue_print_fwd(q,"pushfront");
#endif
    }

    for (int iter = 1;  iter <= 10;  ++iter) {
        char buf[35];
        int len = (rand() % (sizeof(buf) - 1)) + 1;

        int idx = 0;
        for (;  idx < len;  ++idx) {
            int chr = (rand() % 26) + 'a';
            buf[idx] = chr;
        }
        buf[idx] = 0;

        queue_enqueue_back(q, buf);
    }

    queue_print_fwd(q,"Forward");
    queue_print_rev(q,"Reverse");

    // Clean up.
    queue_destroy(q);

    return 0;
}
```