# How to remove last node from a linked list? - C

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to pop the last node from a doubly and circular linked list but I'm getting a headache with pointers. I've got a function that traverses the entire list til the end of it but somehow, the tmp pointer doesn't move or update. I'm traversing the entire list with a for loop instead of a while one as its more comfortable to me (and yes, ive tried with a while loop)

Here is my code:

```c
typedef struct List {
    unsigned int size;
    Node *p_head;
    Node *p_tail;
} List;

typedef struct Node {
    void *p_value;
    struct Node *p_next;
    struct Node *p_previous;
} Node;

Bool RemoveAtEnd(List *list) {

    Node *p_node = list->p_head; /* tmp ptr */

    for (int i = 0; i < GetSize(list); ++i) {
        p_node = (p_node)->p_next;
    }
    
    /*
     * p_node var should be the last node or tail of the list shouldn't it?
     */

    printf("Tail here is %d\n", *(int *) p_node->p_value);
    list->p_tail = p_node->p_previous;
    list->p_tail->p_next = list->p_head;
    list->p_head->p_previous = list->p_tail;
    list->size--;
    DestroyNode(p_node);
    return TRUE;
}
```

When trying to free the node within the function valgrind says "Invalid read" when trying to traverse the list outside the function because as far i seen, the tail is pointing back to the head instead of the tail

````c
    List *p_intList = CreateList();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        int a = i + 1;
        InsertAtEnd(p_intList, &a, sizeof(int));
    }

    RemoveAtEnd(p_intList);

    for (int i = 0; i < GetSize(p_intList); ++i) {
        printf("%d\n", *(int *) GetValueAt(p_intList, i)); // Invalid read
    }

    DestroyList(p_intList);```
````

Comment: If it's a circular doubly linked list, why traverse the whole thing? Shouldn't `head->prev` be the tail you want to remove? This isn't quite a complete example with test cases so it's hard to provide verifiable, executable code.

Comment: What is `List`? Please show a [mcve].

Comment: _Side note:_ With [doubly] linked list, using an index variable and a list count [usually] isn't the best way to traverse. With a singly linked list, just check for a null `p_next` (e.g.): `prev = NULL; for (cur = p_list->head;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->p_next) prev = cur;` With a _doubly_ linked list [as you seem to have], `list->p_tail` is the node to remove, so _no_ traversal is necessary.

Comment: Im used to traverse every linked list this way, its more secure to me, i edited my post

Comment: It may seem "more secure" but it's incredibly inefficient. You're trying to traverse a linked list as you would an array [IMO, possibly, because you don't _really_ understand how linked lists work]. Linked list traversal is O(n), but your traversal: `for (int i = 0; i < GetSize(p_intList); ++i) printf("%d\n", *(int *) GetValueAt(p_intList, i));` takes O(n^2). That is, for a list with 1000 elements, it should be 1000 element accesses but yours does 1,000,000

Comment: alright, in college is what i learnt but in python, im learning C myself this way is the way i work with linked lists, so say i just remove list->p_tail, but how do i update the tail?

Comment: See my recent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70900979/values-arent-being-saved-in-a-queue-in-c/70902192#70902192 Look at the UPDATE section and the `queue_unlink` function

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Something that we can copy/past/compile without guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

in pseudocode i would do like this

you know that   `last-1 ->  last -> head`
and what you need is the list
to become like   `last-1  > head`

1. **save the last node**

   `last = list.getHead()->prev;`
2. **link last-1 with node head**

   `last-1 = list.getHead()->prev->prev;`

   `last-1.next = list.getHead();`
   `list.getHead().prev = last-1`
3. **free removed node**

   `free(last);`